# Switching language (locale) in ActiveAdmin without passing a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, locale, activeadmin, rails-i18n

I want to be able to switch my locale in an [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) app of mine.
So far I've followed [this guide on switching-locale](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Switching-locale), which actually mentions the problem I'm having:

> You will notice, however, that **all links keep the default locale of your app.**

So in my case, once I switch the locale, the urls stay

- `localhost:3000/en/admin/users` instead of
- `localhost:3000/de/admin/users`

The guide also proposes a solution:

> You can override this default locale by passing the locale to all `_path` methods.

But this seems error-prone and quite a lot of work.

So looks like ActiveAdmin uses `I18n.locale` once to create all the urls and does not consider changes to `I18n.locale` after that.

Meaning if you this in your *ApplicationController*:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

I've tried overriding

```
ActiveAdmin::Helpers::Routes.default_url_options
```

in my ApplicationController, which did not help.

Does anyone have an idea how I could resolve this issue?

**Edit:**

I also set these and tried different variations of the `scope` method.

**Routes**

```
scope '(/:locale)', locale: /en|de/, defaults: { locale: I18n.locale }
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

**ApplicationController**

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I've finally figured out what was going on.

I originally followed the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and set my routes.rb:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :books
end
```

which resulted in an error like:

> No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/users"} missing required keys: [:locale]

this was "fixed" by setting

```
scope ':locale', defaults: { locale: I18n.locale } do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

as suggested in the current version of the [Switching locale guide](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Switching-locale).
**But** this has the side-effect of all subsequent url_helpers using this locale for url generation. [BTW at least one other person ran into this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13184).

My current work-around can be [found here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2074):

```
 lib/active_admin/helpers/routes/url_helpers.rb
 def self.default_url_options         
    (Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options.merge({locale: ::I18n.locale})) || {}
 end
```

Now urls are generated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need define :locale scope as optional, this can be done with this code:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
    #your routes
end
```

After in ApplicationController put that code for enable default scoping:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
    options.merge({locale: I18n.locale})
  end
```

Comment: Like I mentioned I've followed the guide which includes both of your suggestions. I'll edit to my question to reflect that though.

Comment: Is I18n.default_locale defined?

Comment: Put please your routes.rb

Comment: I just did. Not sure what you mean with "defined" but `I18.default_locale` always defaults to `:en` according to rails documentation in my `application.rb`.

Comment: Put the parentesis in your :locales as I suggested, look my scope and yours

Comment: After do that please reset the server

Comment: I tried `(:locale)` and a couple of others (see edited post) but nothing changed.